# What does the comma mean in this commutation rule between quantum operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation, commutator

The Theorem about quantum operators commutation relation says:

> Consider pairs $(U, V )$ of unitary representations on a
>   Hilbert space $H$, satisfying the commutation rule:
>   $$U(x) V(y)=\exp (i \omega(x, y)) V(y) U(x).$$
>   Such pairs are all equivalent to
>   multiples of the standard Schrödinger representation on $L^2(\Re^n)$.

The comma between $x$ and  $y$, does it mean inner product or it means something else?

References:

1. J. Rosenberg *A Selective History of the Stone-von Neumann Theorem,* https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/StoneVNart.pdf page 6.

Comment: This is just a guess, but isn't it just a function $\omega: G\times G\rightarrow \mathbb R$, so $x$ and $y$ are just elements of the group and the function $\omega$ has two arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\omega$ is presumably a bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, cf. the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group). In other words, the comma separates the two arguments $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ of $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried to derive it by defining U(x)=exp(ixP) and V(y)=exp(iyQ) where P and Q are canonical operators but I did not know how to get the final result as in the original question. Can I derive it by defining U and V like this? If yes can you give me a small hint?